# Fullcalendar js how to build from source

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, fullcalendar, bundling-and-minification

I have downloaded a version of the fullcalendar from this link -> https://github.com/PaulAik/fullcalendar

How can i build the final fullcalendar.js file from source?

The readme file says: "You must have a Java runtime environment (accessible by the java command) for minification. Then, run make zip and check the dist/ directory for your newly created ZIP archive. To start fresh, run the make clean command."

I have the java runtime installed and i tried to run "make zip" by the commandline but it doesn't work. I use Windows7.

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/wiki/Contributing-Code

```
npm install -g grunt-cli bower
git clone git://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar.git
cd fullcalendar && npm install
grunt
```